# Determining Code Errors using GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

So I'm given a chunk the chunk of code below and told their are three errors in it. Okay that's great. I'm to use the "Core" file and gdb to look through the code.

I however, am really bad an comprehending what I am looking at. I'm told to run gdb using the command:

gdb print_test core

but I don't actually know what the "core" argument does or what to do after that. my knowledge of gdb is sadly limited to the absolute basic. Any advice to proceed is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "natural.h"


/* This program is a test driver for arbitrary precision addition.  It expects
 * two integers expressed in hex as command-line arguments.  Naturals, however,
 * are read from streams.  Libc has a memory stream.  These look like file
 * streams, but they actually "read" from the strings.  This lets us read two
 * natural numbers, add them together, and display the results.  There is a
 * little bookkeeping at the end to free or release the memory used by the
 * natural numbers.  These would be destructors or finalizers in C++ or Java.
 */
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   natural_t l,r,s;
   FILE* fmem;

   if (argc != 3)  {
  fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s {hexdigits} {hexdigits}\n", argv[0]);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   fmem = fmemopen(argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), "r");
   l = read_natural(fmem);
   fclose(fmem);

   fmem = fmemopen(argv[2], strlen(argv[2]), "r");
   r = read_natural(fmem);
   fclose(fmem);

   s = add_naturals(l,r);

   print_natural(stdout, s);
   printf("\n");

   release_natural (&l);
   release_natural (&r);
   release_natural (&s);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: In addition to my answer below, the driver program looks pretty sane, all things considered. I'd assume your problem lies somewhere in the code for operating on natural numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also have a file called "core". This is a core dump, which is optionally generated when a program crashes (if the `ulimit` core dump size is set to non-zero). This is effectively a snapshot of your program's working memory at the time that it crashed, thus can be inspected by a post-mortem debugger, which is what you're using GDB for here.

GDB is run by `gdb [program] [core_dump]`, so by running `gdb print_test core`, you're running GDB on the program "print_test", and with the core dump "core". From here, you can use gdb like normal. The first port of call would be to run the "backtrace" command to ascertain where the program crashed, and use the "print " command to print out the contents of variables. From here, you'd have to look up a GDB manual for more information, as a full introduction to GDB is out of the scope of this answer.